# Maintain logged in state and scrape JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I have some JavaScript behind a login that I need to scrape. This JavaScript is triggered at the click of a radio button, thus exposing the elements which I need to scrape.

Selenium and PhantomJS do not maintain the logged in state brought about by the requests library.

```
session = requests.Session()
h = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/x-www-form-urlencoded; q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"}

i = session.get(url, headers=h)
b = BeautifulSoup(i.text, "html.parser")
# Frm login
frm = b.find("input", {"name":"frmLogin"})
frmval = frm.attrs['value']
# Login token
tok = b.find("input", {"name":"submitToken"})
tokval = tok.attrs['value']
# target
targ = b.find("input", {"name":"target"})
targval = targ.attrs['value']
# hdn_mobile
hdnm = b.find("input", {"name":"hdn_mobile"})
hdnmval = hdnm.attrs['value']

params = {'frmLogin:strCustomerLogin_userID': username, 'frmLogin:strCustomerLogin_pwd': password, 'frmLogin': frmval, 'submitToken': tokval, 'target': targval, 'hdn_mobile': hdnmval, 'frmLogin:btnLogin1.x': '0', 'frmLogin:btnLogin1.y': '0'}
r = session.post(urlact, data=params, headers=h)
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='../p/bin/phantomjs')
g = session.get(url2, headers=h)
d = BeautifulSoup(g.text, "html.parser")
```

I am aware of the `seleniumrequests` library however there seems to be no concrete documentation surrounding its use.

How can I maintain this logged in state, execute the JS and then scrape the result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Session parameters usually saved in cookies, so you have to transfer cookies from responce `i = session.get(url, headers=h)` to `h` before you call `r = session.post(urlact, data=params, headers=h)`

You always have to get cookies from response and put them to next request